# Using proxy, using curl, working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, curl, proxy, vps

I setup a proxy on one of my vps using squid, then i made this proxy script and it works fine on wamp, on localhost but when i upload it to my server its not working and I cannot seem to figure out why.

```
$proxy = "xx.xx.xxx.xx:3128";
$proxy = explode(':', $proxy);
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/1.0 (googlebot@googlebot.com http://googlebot.com/)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://tamilwin.com/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

thanks in advance.

Update

the error i get on my server is `cURL error number:7cURL error:couldn't connect to host`

Comment: Its not working? How what errors or responses do you get?

Comment: the error i get is cURL error number:7cURL error:couldn't connect to host

Comment: that means curl couldn't connect to that port on that IP

Comment: that's because you're trying to swindle

Answer (score 0):

The proxy host may be not valid.
try telnet xx.xx.xxx.xx 3128 (from your local PC)
Can you connect to it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems, works great on localhost but not on my server. I wrote a detection script which lets you know if it works or not.

```
<?php

//$url = 'https://www.google.com';
// to check your proxy
$url = 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/';
$proxy = 'x.x.x.x:3128';

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true ); // read more about HTTPS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162706/how-to-scrape-a-ssl-or-https-url/31164409#31164409
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, file_exists('\cacert.pem'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, $proxy);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 

//echo $output;

$check = stripos($output,'</html>');
// if there was a match in the stripos (string postion) function echo that the
//proxy got the data and works
if($check > 0)
{
echo $proxy." Works!
";
// or else echo it doesn't work
}else{
echo $proxy." Is Dead!
";
}


?>
```