# Curl not working with http/socks proxy on a live server

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl, php-5.2

Duplicate : [Using proxy, using curl, working on localhost but not on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045882/using-proxy-using-curl-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-server) but unanswered and I've already tried what it says, no use.

I tried connecting to my dedicated server through SSH and tried using socks/http proxies both, but both of them return error 7. Although the same script works fine on my local XAMPP with both http & socks proxy.

I've already created a ticket about it for the server support. But I'll be glad to know the reason behind and if possible how to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure curl is installed on your server? or it allows you to connect with proxy. Some servers detect you are trying to connect with proxy. may be this will be issue

Comment: @DarkWish thanks for the reply. a) yes it works fine on the server, without the proxy setting. b) it works fine on my machine with/without the proxy setting. c) it doesn't work on the server with the proxy setting. I tried curl command line through SSH on my server and I'm getting error 7 for both http & socks proxy.

Comment: @DarkWish I just contacted the server people and seems like it was more of a firewall issue. The curl now works fine and connects to both http/socks proxies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue, on localhost was fine, but on the live server didn't worked (header 0).

I turned off CSF Firewall and the curl worked ok, then i allowed the port in firewal configuration, turned on the firewall and everything is working ok now.