# How to scrape a SSL or HTTPS URL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have written a function to scrape a website using CURL but it returns nothing when called and can't understand why. The output is empty

```
  <?php
    function scrape($url)
    {
        $headers = Array(
                    "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5",
                    "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
                    "Connection: keep-alive",
                    "Keep-Alive: 300",
                    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                    "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
                    "Pragma: "
                );
        $config = Array(
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE ,
                        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE ,
                        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE ,
                        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120 ,
                        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120 ,
                        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10 ,                   
                        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8" ,
                        CURLOPT_URL => $url ,
                       ) ;
        $handle = curl_init() ;
        curl_setopt_array($handle,$config) ;
        curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers) ;
        $data = curl_exec($handle) ;
        curl_close($handle) ;
        return $data ;
    }

    echo scrape("https://www.google.com") ;
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 possible fixes when trying to scrape a ssl or https url:

1. The quick fix
2. The proper fix

The quick fix, first.

**Warning: this can introduce security issues that SSL is designed to protect against.**

set: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false`

The second, and proper fix. Set 3 options:

1. `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true`
2. `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2`
3. `CURLOPT_CAINFO => getcwd() . '\CAcert.pem'`

The last thing you need to do is download the CA certificate.

Go to, - http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html -> click 'cacert.pem' -> copie/paste the text in to a text editor -> save the file as 'CAcert.pem' Check it isn't 'CAcert.pem.**txt**'

```
<?php
    function scrape($url)
    {
        $headers = Array(
                    "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5",
                    "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
                    "Connection: keep-alive",
                    "Keep-Alive: 300",
                    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                    "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
                    "Pragma: "
                );
        $config = Array(
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
                        CURLOPT_CAINFO => getcwd() . '\CAcert.pem',
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE ,
                        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE ,
                        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE ,
                        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120 ,
                        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120 ,
                        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10 ,                   
                        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8" ,
                        CURLOPT_URL => $url
                       ) ;
        $handle = curl_init() ;
        curl_setopt_array($handle,$config) ;
        curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers) ;
        $output->data = curl_exec($handle) ;

        if(curl_exec($handle) === false) {
            $output->error = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($handle);
        } else {
            $output->error = 'Operation completed without any errors';
        }

        curl_close($handle) ;
        return $output ;
    }

$scrape = scrape("https://www.google.com") ;

echo $scrape->data;

//uncomment for errors
//echo $scrape->error;
?>
```

Comment: I get this error now Curl error: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\php_inc\CAcert.pem CApath: none

Comment: Could be a couple things. But lets just start with your path, copy/paste that url in to your browser does it find the file?? if not, you are not using the right path.

Comment: I used `file_exists()` and it worked. The path exists

Comment: I mean the path to your CAcert. pem file