# file_get_contents with https requests via proxy

Tags: php, https, proxy, fsockopen

How to do HTTPS requests via proxy server

The proxy server is `tinyproxy` on debian

## code

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'proxy' => 'tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:8888',
        'request_fulluri' => true
    ]
]);

echo file_get_contents('https://www.google.com', false, $context);
```

## error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in C:\wamp\www\google\test.php on line 10

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com): failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy in C:\wamp\www\google\test.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend cURL to do this. Somewhere on stackoverflow a user said this and I totally agree.

> file_get_contents() is a simple screwdriver. Great for simple GET
>   requests where the header, HTTP request method, timeout, cookiejar,
>   redirects, and other important things do not matter. cURL with setopt
>   is a powerdrills with almost every option you can think of.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.google.com';
// to check your proxy
// $url = 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/';
$proxy = '50.115.194.97:8080';

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // read more about HTTPS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162706/how-to-scrape-a-ssl-or-https-url/31164409#31164409
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: This worked for me, I was using `file_get_contents()` but the response was false, after trying this code it worked. Thanks @PHPhil

Comment: That's an awful quote. [`file_get_contents` supports POST and other verbs, custom headers, time-outs, cookies and automatic redirect following](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). This cURL fanboying needs to stop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem which causes your second warning can be fixed by changing 'http' in stream_context_create to 'https'

Comment: This only works because the options (and the proxy) are ignored. Special options for https can be added to the options with the key 'ssl', the key 'https' does nothing!