# If/else for https connection through proxy

Tags: php, if-statement, proxy

I am using this code to check a proxy server, before doing anything else. When the connection is ok, I have a `file_get_contents` line to connect to a website.

```
$host = '123.45.678.90'; 
$port = 80; 
$waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
    $aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
    'proxy' => 'tcp://123.45.678.90:80',
    'request_fulluri' => true,
    ),
    );
    $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

    // connect to website using a proxy server
    $file_content = file_get_contents('https://www.anything.com', False, $cxContext);
} else {
   // It didn't work 
} 
fclose($fp);
```

But though the proxy connection was succesfull, I see this: **Warning** `Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy`? Is there any chance to have an if/else statement, that allows me to do something if there is no warning and stop doing something if there is a warning? I have looked and googled a lot, but haven't found anything I could try.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What OpenSSL-Version does `phpinfo();` show?

Comment: It shows me **OpenSSL/1.0.1t**

Comment: Are you running on windows?

Comment: No, I am using a Mac.

Comment: Your OpenSSl version seems outdated and it may be the source of the problem, try to update it, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/126832

Answer (score 0):

try to use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents` and it will work

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.google.com';
// to check your proxy
// $url = 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/';
$proxy = '50.115.194.97:8080';

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // read more about HTTPS     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162706/how-to-scrape-a-ssl-or-https-    url/31164409#31164409
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1;     en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 

echo $output;

?>
```

from [PHPhil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634604/file-get-contents-with-https-requests-via-proxy)

Comment: Your solution probably works, but it doesn't address the OP's problem, or has any value to future users with the same problem.

Comment: file_get_contents() is a simple screwdriver. Great for simple GET requests where the header, HTTP request method, timeout, cookiejar, redirects, and other important things do not matter. cURL with setopt is a powerdrills with almost every option you can think of.

Comment: Puuuh, I am really very new to cURL. I don not know how to use it or how to get an if/else in there.

Comment: just put the if and else for this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
`

Comment: @vloryan Your problem is related to an outdated version of `OpenSSL` and it doesn't matter if you use `cUrl` or `file_get_contents()`, it won't work unless you set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false`, which is **unsafe**

Comment: Hm, ok. I think I can't update the `OpenSSL` version on my shared hosting. Damn! Is there a workaround for _if there is a warning, do this, else do that_?

Answer (score 0):

`if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)` doesn't make sense, if this proxy is working, you can simply use:

```
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://123.45.678.90:80',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
    ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$file_content = file_get_contents('https://google.com', False, $cxContext);
print $file_content;
```