# can't scrape data - from httpswebsite

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am  trying to get some country name from one of website. that website URL starting with https  so  i am not able to scrape data. please give me some solution.

Here is my code :

```
$curl = curl_init('https://testing.co/india');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {`enter code here`
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}
curl_close($curl);
$regex = '/<a class="startup-link">(.*?)<\/a>/s';
if (preg_match($regex, $page, $list))
    echo $list[0];
else
    print "Not found";
```

Get this error : `Scraper error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: Please go through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162706/how-to-scrape-a-ssl-or-https-url

Answer (score 0):

Today i am solving this problem and i came to know about it.

See. Below is code that is working for me.

```
// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.<br/>
$url = "https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl";<br/>
$ch = curl_init();<br/>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);<br/><br/>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);<br/>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);<br/>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);<br/>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt");
    <br/>
// Get the response and close the channel.<br/>
$response = curl_exec($ch);<br/>
$link = fopen("data.txt","w+");<br/>
fputs($link,$response);<br/>
fclose($link);<br/>
curl_close($ch);<br/>
```

You have pass certificate on this.. 
On Mozilla firefox left handside of website URL you get one information icon. Then click on Security tab then find View certificate. Click on Details Tab.
See Certificate Hierarchy Section. Click on top most label and see below there is an option as EXPORT. Export that certificate and save the CA certificate to your selected location, making sure to select the X.509 Certificate (PEM) as the save type/format.

e.g.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt");

Now save it and run.. You will get the data..

Answer (score -1):

use

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
```